# Calculator using Select in javascriot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written this code for selecting an action and to be processed by clicking the calculate button and resetting the field by clicking the reset but unfortunately, it is not working and I also need to change the color of options when any action is selected like the calculate button become + when I select add, - for sub, etc. This code is not working properly

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10%; line-height: 40px;">
            Number 1<input type="number" id="num1"><br>
            Number 2<input type="number" id="num2"><br>

            <select id="dom" onchange="show_dom(this.value)">
                <option value="">Select an Operation</option>
                <option value="add">Addition</option>
                <option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
                <option value="divide">Division</option>
                <option value="mul">Multiplication</option>

            </select><br>

            Result:<input type="text" name="" id="result" disabled><br>
            <input type="button" name="" onclick="calculate();" value="Calculate">
            <input type="button" name="" onclick="clear();" value="Reset">

            <script type="text/javascript">

                function add(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function sub(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)-parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function divide(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)/parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function mul(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)*parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function clear(){
                 document.getElementById("result").value = "";
                }

                function show_dom(){
                 switch(dom.value){
                    case "add"{
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                            }
                    case "sub"{
                        n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)-parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                            }
                    case "divide"{
                        n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)/parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                            }

                    case "mul"{
                        n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)*parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                            }       

                }
            }

            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Switch-case` syntax is wrong .Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) for correct syntax

Comment: you forgot to add logic to calculate() function

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;margin: 10%; line-height: 40px;">
            Number 1<input type="number" id="num1"><br>
            Number 2<input type="number" id="num2"><br>
            <!-- onchange="show_dom(this.value)" -->
            <select id="dom" >
                <option value="">Select an Operation</option>
                <option value="add">Addition</option>
                <option value="sub">Subtraction</option>
                <option value="divide">Division</option>
                <option value="mul">Multiplication</option>
            </select><br>

            Result:<input type="text" name="" id="result" disabled><br>
            <button id="Calculate">
                Calculate
            </button>
            <button  id="Reset">
                Clear
            </button>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var Calc = document.getElementById("Calculate");
            var Reset = document.getElementById("Reset");
            Calc.addEventListener("click" , calc)
            function calc(){
            var dom = document.getElementById("dom");
            dom.addEventListener("change" , show_dom())
                function add(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)+parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function sub(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)-parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function divide(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;
                    res=parseInt(n1) / parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }

                function mul(){
                    var n1,n2,res;
                    n1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                    n2=document.getElementById("num2").value;

                    res=parseInt(n1)*parseInt(n2);
                    document.getElementById("result").value=res;
                }
                
                Reset.addEventListener("click" , clear)
                function clear(){
                 document.getElementById("result").value = "";
                }

                function show_dom(){
                 switch(dom.value){
                    case "add" :
                        add()
                        break;

                    case "sub" :
                        sub()
                        break;
                            
                    case "divide" :
                        divide()
                        break;
                            

                    case "mul":
                        mul()
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
            </script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes